# How to increment the body of the payload in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, payload

```
{
  "productIds" : 
[
    "p1": "value1"
  ]
}

{
  "productIds" : 
[
    "p1": "value2"
  ]
}

{
  "productIds" : 
[
    "p1": "value3"
  ]
}
```

i want the above data part to be saved in a variable and to be printed for 1000 times in the payload with p1 having dynamic value for every part,.

Answer (score 1):

Either use [Counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) configuration element or [__counter() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) instead of `1` hard-coded value:

```
 { "productIds" : [ "p1": "value${__counter(FALSE,)}" ] }
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test)

Comment: hi i want the p1 value to be incremented in the payload request, not in the response